# Solve the differential $2(2x+3)^2 y''+ 3(2x+3)y' - 2y = \tan(\ln(2x+3)) $

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I've tried solving this using Legendre's method and the reached the particular integral as
PI =$\dfrac{\tan(z)}{8D^2 - 2D - 2}\quad$ where $\quad z = \ln(2x+3)$.

Comment: This does not fit the pattern where the "method of guessing" or "undetermined coefficients" works. You have to use the variation-of-parameters approach.